# Is there any way to automate or bypass Google captcha in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation, captcha

I am automating a website, theres a Google captcha because of this i had to run my code in debug mode, so that i can solve the captcha and run the code ahead.
Is there any way to automate or bypass the google captcha?

Comment: Given that the entire purpose of the captcha is to make it so that it can't be automated or bypassed, of course there is no way to do so that could be posted as a SO answer.

Comment: For a legitimate use of the website, the website owner should provide you with appropriate access. Otherwise, the captcha does exactly what it should.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, resolving a CAPTCHA cannot be automated: Otherwise it could not tell computers and humans apart and hence fails to be a CAPTCHA.

To handle a CAPTCHA in a test environment you can do:

- Ask your development team to remove the CAPTCHA field on the test environment.
- Ask your development team to make a sandbox like CAPTCHA, that will accept a single input text every time